# Why does declaring a character string parameter in a function needs a pointer in C?

Tags: c

Can anyone please explain, why there is a need to include an "asterisk" (`*`) in a character string parameter declaration in a function?

```
#include <stdio.h>

void func2(char *fName);

int main() {
    char name[20];

    printf("What is your name? ");
    scanf("%s", name);
    //some code here

}

void func2(char *fName) {
    //some code here
}
```

Comment: The _parameter_ in `func2(char *fName)` is not a _string_.  `fName` is a pointer to a _string_.

Comment: where are you using func2? what func2 is doing?

Answer (score 4):

An intuitive reason is that character strings can take different lengths. As it is not possible to define a "one size fits all" parameter type, you need to use a pointer to indicate the beginning of your character string in your function parameters.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, note that, C language does not have native *string* type. In C, strings are actually one-dimensional *array* of characters terminated by a null character `\0`.

Quoting C11, 6.3.2.1p3 *[emphasis added]*

> Except when it is the operand of the sizeof operator, the _Alignof operator, or the unary & operator, or is a string literal used to initialize an array, **an expression that has type ''array of type'' is converted to an expression with type ''pointer to type'' that points to the initial element of the array object** and is not an lvalue.

The declarations

```
void func2 (char fName[]);
void func2 (char fName[20]);
void func2 (char fName[100]);
```

are exactly same as

```
void func2 (char *fName);
```

This **conversion** of array-like declarators into pointers holds only within function formal parameter declarations, nowhere else. Check **[this](http://c-faq.com/aryptr/aryptrparam.html)**.

In the program, when you pass array `name` to a function

```
int main (void) {
    char name[20];
    ......
    func2 (name);
    ......
```

the argument `name`, which is array of type `char`, is converted to pointer of type `char` that points to the initial element of the array `name`.

Consider this example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void func2 (char *fName);
void func3 (char fName[]);
void func4 (char fName[20]);
void func5 (char fName[1]);

int main (void) {
    char name[20];

    printf ("What is your name? ");
    scanf ("%19s", name);
    func2 (name);
    func3 (name);
    func4 (name);
    func5 (name);
    return 0;
}

void func2 (char *fName) {
    printf ("In func2, name: %s\n", fName);
}

void func3 (char fName[]) {
    printf ("In func3, name: %s\n", fName);
}

void func4(char fName[20]) {
    printf ("In func4, name: %s\n", fName);
}

void func5 (char fName[1]) {
    printf ("In func5, name: %s\n", fName);
}
```

Compile

```
# gcc -Wall -Wextra prg.c
#
```

Execute

```
# ./a.out 
What is your name? Gem
In func2, name: Gem
In func3, name: Gem
In func4, name: Gem
In func5, name: Gem
```

Answer (score 2):

The answer is in several parts:

1. C has no built-in, first-class string type.
2. Type `char` is for holding *single* characters like `'c'`.  A variable of type `char` cannot hold a multi-character string like `"cat"` (or even, for that matter, a single-character string like `"c"`).
3. In C, strings are implemented as null-terminated *arrays* of `char`.
4. Arrays are second-class citizens in C.  You cannot assign one array to another, or pass an array to a function.
5. When you try to assign an array, or pass it to a function, or in fact do anything where it seems like the value of the array would be needed, what you get instead is a pointer to the array's first element.

So that's why functions that operate on strings receive arguments of type `char *`.  The original string was an array of `char`, but somewhere along the way before the function received it the string got represented as a pointer to its first element.

If you're used to languages where there *is* a true, built-in, first-class string type, where manipulating strings (and using operators and functions to create new strings) is as straightforward as operating on integers, characters, and floating-point values, then C can be pretty confusing at first.  In C, whenever you work with strings, there are always pointers involved, and you always have to think about details like where the pointers point, and whether the pointer points to enough memory for the string it's trying to reference, and whether there's a proper null terminator.  Once you're used to it, this is all easy enough to do, but it is something you have to think a little extra about.

Answer (score 1):

When declaring parameters to functions, declaring an array variable(one dimensional array of characters) without size is equivalent to declaring a pointer. Often this is done to emphasize the fact that the pointer variable will be used in a manner equivalent to an array.

```
/* two equivalent function definitions */

 void func2( char *fName );
 void func2( char fName[] );
```

Hope this will make you even more clear.

Answer (score 0):

when passing a string, all that actually gets passed is a pointer to the string